# Plotting a function in R with multiple values for variable

Tags: r

I need to plot in R a function of the log likelihood. I have a fixed n, multiple values for k and arbitrary pi between 0 and 1.
I tried this code but the result is not what i want:

```
n<-10
k<-c(8,8,5,4,6)
pi = seq(0,1,length=100)
l = function(pi){k*log(pi) + (n-k) * log(1-pi)}
plot(x=pi,y=l(pi),ylab="l(pi)",xlab="q",type="l",ylim=c(-10,0))
```

[the plot is far from a normal curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ztJl.png)

please help

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `curve`. Just define your function in first `curve` argument, using `x` as variable, and the first `k[1]`. In a second step loop the same over the remaining `k[2:5]` using `add=TRUE` argument.

```
n <- 10
k <- c(7,8,5,4,6)

curve(k[1]*log(x) + (n-k[1]) * log(1-x), ylim=c(-40, 0))
invisible(sapply(seq(k[-1]) + 1, function(i)
  curve(k[i]*log(x) + (n-k[i]) * log(1-x), col=i, add=TRUE)))
legend("bottomright", legend=k, lty=1, col=1:5, title="k", horiz=T, cex=.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how R handles your 'multiple values of `k`'.

Because `k` is a vector of length 5, and `pi` is a vector of length 100, `k` is 'recycled', meaning that R pairs each `pi` with a value of `k` in turn:

```
pi: 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05           0.06 0.07 0.08
k:    8    8    5    4    6 [back to:]   8    8    5 ...
```

Instead, you want to plot each *k* separately:

```
pi = seq(0, 1, length = 100)
l = function(pi, k) k * log(pi) + (n-k) * log(1-pi)
plot(x = pi, y = l(pi, 8), ylab="l(pi)", xlab = "q",
     ylim = c(-10, 0))
lines(x = pi, y = l(pi, 5), col = 'red')
lines(x = pi, y = l(pi, 4), col = 'blue')
lines(x = pi, y = l(pi, 6), col = 'orange')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: would making pi of length 5 do any better?

Comment: Did you try this in R and see what happened?  Your `pi` values correspond to points on the _x_ axis at which the function _l(pi)_ is evaluated. With five entries in _pi_, you'd end up with just five points.